# Why are values pulled from a data frame coded with different characters (å > a)?

Tags: r

When I pull unique values from a column of a data frame containing characters ä, ö and å in Rstudio, words with "å" get printed with "a" instead, and when I want to remove some words containing "å", I can remove them neither by using å, nor by using a. Why does it change å to a and what coding should I use to remove the words?

I have a data frame with words containing characters ä, ö and å. I tried to pull unique values from a column, and then write text lines using writeLines. The pulled object codes å as a (ö and ä work fine). I wanted to remove some verbs that contain å such as må or måste by using -which, but they stay when coded as "maste" as well as "måste". When I then want to filter the verbs in the original data frame according to the verbs vector, it works even for the verbs in the vector that had "a" instead of "å". I'm an R beginner so I don't know how to reproduce the df (sorry!)

df CONTAINS DIFFERENT SWEDISH VERBS UNDER verb.lemma (|åka|, |göra|, |tala|, |veta|, |måste|, |må|)

> verbs <- pull(df, var = "verb.lemma") %>% unique() %>% sort()
>   writeLines(verbs, sep = ", ")
>   verbs <- verbs[-which(verbs %in% c("|göra|", "|måste|"))]
>
> ## OR
>
> verbs <- verbs[-which(verbs %in% c("|göra|", "|maste|"))]
>
> verbs
>
> df1 <- filter(df, verb.lemma %in% verbs)

- THE SECOND LINE OF THE CODE PRODUCES AN OBJECT THAT LOOKS LIKE THIS: |aka|, |göra|, |maste|, |ma|, |tala|, |veta|,
- THE FOURTH LINE PRODUCES |aka|, |maste|, |ma|, |tala|, |veta|,
- THE FIFTH LINE PRODUCES df1 WITH verb.lemma CONTAINING |åka|, |tala|, |veta|, |måste|, |må|

Any tips will be very much appreciated!